# In haxe macro, how can I get a type by using a Type name

Tags: macros, haxe

In the haxe expression macro I have the following code:

```
var t = haxe.macro.Context.getType("h2d.Object");
```

I'd like to get the type without using a string. Something like this:

```
var t = callX(h2d.Object);
```

The question is what `callX` should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [type reification](https://haxe.org/manual/macro-reification-type.html) and then convert a ComplexType to your desired type, like so

```
var t1 = Context.getType("haxe.format.JsonParser");
var t2 = ComplexTypeTools.toType(macro:haxe.format.JsonParser);
trace(t1, t2);
```

```
TInst(haxe.format.JsonParser,[]),TInst(haxe.format.JsonParser,[])
```

and if you need to allow passing a type to the macro, you can use `Context.typeof(expr)`, which would give you a `TType(Class<haxe.format.JsonParser>,[])`

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for. I really wish docs for macros were better. Amazing functionality but so much trial and error.

Comment: There are some practical examples in the [Cookbook](https://code.haxe.org/category/macros/), but still - macros are one of the trickier parts of the language, especially as it comes to more exotic manipulations.